# Reference error : Google is not defined

Tags: performance-testing, gatling

I am using Gatling tool to load test my website which has google maps, i am getting the above mentioned error when i record test cases from Gatling, But when I browse website without Gatling it works fine. Please assist.

Code:

```
val httpProtocol = http
    .baseURL("http://staging.user.com")
    .inferHtmlResources()

val headers_0 = Map("Accept" -> "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8")

val headers_1 = Map("Accept" -> "text/css,*/*;q=0.1")

val headers_2 = Map("Accept" -> "*/*")

val headers_19 = Map(
    "Accept" -> "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01",
    "X-Requested-With" -> "XMLHttpRequest")

val uri1 = "static.hotjar.com"
val uri2 = "http://www.google-analytics.com"
val uri3 = "http://staging.user.com/user"
val uri4 = "www.googletagmanager.com"

val scn = scenario("RecordedSimulation")
    .exec(http("request_0")
        .get("/user/sulogin.html")
        .headers(headers_0)
        .resources(http("request_1")
        .get(uri3 + "/resources-Andromeda.1742/css/login.css")
        .headers(headers_1)
        .check(status.is(304)),
        http("request_2")
        .get(uri3 + "/resources-Andromeda.1742/js/analytics/google_tag_manager.js")
        .headers(headers_2),
        http("request_3")
        .get(uri3 + "/resources-Andromeda.1742/js/login/loginHandler.js")
        .headers(headers_2),
        http("request_4")
        .get(uri3 + "/resources-Andromeda.1742/images/sidebar_login_top.png")
        .check(status.is(304)),
        http("request_5")
        .get(uri3 + "/resources-Andromeda.1742/js/libraries/jquery/jquery.validate-1.13.1.min.js")
        .headers(headers_2),
        http("request_6")
        .get(uri3 + "/resources-Andromeda.1742/images/user_fleet_logo.png")
        .check(status.is(304)),
        http("request_7")
        .get(uri3 + "/resources-Andromeda.1742/images/sidebar_login_bottom.png")
        .check(status.is(304)),
        http("request_8")
        .get(uri3 + "/images/breadcrumb_top.png")
        .check(status.is(304)),
        http("request_9")
        .get(uri3 + "/images/bg_login.png")
        .check(status.is(304)),
        http("request_10")
        .get(uri3 + "/resources-Andromeda.1742/js/libraries/jquery/jquery-1.8.3.min.js")
        .headers(headers_2)))
    .pause(5)
    .exec(http("request_11")
        .get("http://" + uri4 + "/gtm.js?id=GTM-KW4P7K")
        .headers(headers_2)
        .resources(http("request_12")
        .get(uri2 + "/analytics.js")
        .headers(headers_2)
        .check(status.is(304)),
        http("request_13")
        .get(uri2 + "/collect?v=1&_v=j41&a=2011589431&t=pageview&_s=1&dl=http%3A%2F%2Fstaging.user.com%2Fuser%2Fsulogin.html&ul=en-us&de=windows-1252&dt=user%20Customer%20Login&sd=24-bit&sr=1366x768&vp=1366x659&je=0&fl=21.0%20r0&_u=QAEAAAABI~&jid=&cid=44054207.1439273009&tid=UA-40333098-1&gtm=GTM-KW4P7K&z=2099200825")))
    .pause(1)
    .exec(http("request_14")
        .post("/user/j_spring_security_check?back_url=")
        .headers(headers_0)
        .formParam("targetCustomer", "***")
        .formParam("j_username", "****")
        .formParam("j_password", "****")
        .formParam("LOGIN", "LOGIN")
        .resources(http("request_15")
        .get(uri3 + "/custom/css/get?time=1459314853496")
        .headers(headers_1),
        http("request_16")
        .get("http://" + uri1 + "/c/hotjar-137185.js?sv=5")
        .headers(headers_2)
        .check(status.is(304)),
        http("request_17")
        .get(uri3 + "/custom/logo.png?version=1459314853497")))
    .pause(3)
    .exec(http("request_18")
        .get(uri2 + "/collect?v=1&_v=j41&a=254846444&t=pageview&_s=1&dl=http%3A%2F%2Fstaging.user.com%2Fuser%2Fmap.html%3Fl%3Den_US&ul=en-us&de=windows-1252&dt=user&sd=24-bit&sr=1366x768&vp=1366x659&je=0&fl=21.0%20r0&_u=QAEAAAABI~&jid=&cid=44054207.1439273009&tid=UA-40333098-1&gtm=GTM-KW4P7K&z=1352870067")
        .resources(http("request_19")
        .post(uri3 + "/getUserUnitPref.json")
        .headers(headers_19),
        http("request_20")
        .get(uri3 + "/getUserPrivileges.json?_=1459314859620")
        .headers(headers_19)))

setUp(scn.inject(atOnceUsers(1))).protocols(httpProtocol)
}
```

Comment: Relevant code snippets... ?

Comment: Please mention the complete `stackTrace`

Comment: @VikrantKashyap In browser console it is throwing the above mentioned error

Comment: you configured the gatling recorder as a proxy in your browser, right?

Comment: Yes @Meiko, you are right.

Comment: maybe the problem is how the javascript files are loaded... a timing issue... how do you load the google api in the html file.

Comment: After login, we use google api library to call those apis.